# What is the difference between System.Drawing.Point and System.Drawing.PointF

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing

What is the difference between `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Drawing.PointF`.
Can you give an example between this two.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check msdn for [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) and [PointF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.aspx) and especially compare the datatype of the X and Y properties.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question sounded like something the OP could figure out himself, at least the "difference" part.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think `PointF` exists partly because `System.Drawing.Graphics` class supports transformation and anti-aliasing. For example, you can draw a line between discrete pixelx in anti-aliasing mode.

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Pen pen = Pens.Red;
        // draw two vertical line
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(100, 100), new Point(100, 200));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(103, 100), new Point(103, 200));
        // draw a line exactly in the middle of those two lines
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new PointF(101.5f, 200.0f), new PointF(101.5f, 300.0f)); ;
    }
```

and it will look like

[image: this]

without `PointF` those functionalities will be limited.

Answer (score 31):

`Point` uses integer coordinates (`int` for `X` and `Y`).

`PointF` uses floating points (`float` for `X` and `Y`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But where can I use `PointF`?

Comment: In almost all the methods on `System.Drawing.Graphics`. For example, `Graphics.DrawLine` can take either `Point` or `PointF` parameters.

Comment: @Timwi thanks, so PointF cannot be use on user control properties? for example `Location`?

Comment: @Rye: I believe most of Windows Forms uses an integer coordinate system, whereas most of WPF uses a `double`-based coordinate system.

Comment: There is also `System.Windows.Point`, which uses double coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

For Example,In some embedded systems,only support "System.Drawing.Point",you should create  "PointF" Type by yourself .